# Using full names as primary key vs creating an additional field

Tags: mysql, relational-database

Assume we have two tables. One is for movies. The movie table has fields for the movies name, and year of release, as well as which actor starred in it. The other table is for lead actors. It has fields for the name of the actor, and their date of birth.

The date of birth field depends on the name field. Would it make sense to use actors full names as a primary key? What if performance is not an issue?

Comment: A primary key have to be unique and actor names don't assure this.

Comment: Also, actors have been known to change their names from time to time, and PK values should not change throughout the lifetime of the data.

Comment: Even barring the uniqueness issues already raised (which should be enough to dissuade you), why would you want to?

Comment: To have one less field, simply. I should probably have asked about a table with a single field instead, such as a genre. Assume that for some arbitrary reason, it has to be made into a separate table.

Comment: If you were to do that with the name, you have one less (4-byte usually) int field in the "actors" table, but end up with two (much larger) char or varchar fields in every table that must reference actors. As far as that genre table goes, you could just have a varchar field in the movies table, but you'd need to `select distinct genre from movies` whenever you wanted to post a list of currently registered genres... and that could make multiple (mis)spellings harder to manage as well.

Comment: About the only reason to put text fields everywhere in a database is for human readability. It pretty much destroys the efficiency (for speed AND storage requirements) to do so. At which point, you are better off using a spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily it makes no sense at all to use a name field, even a full name field, as a primary key. That's because you want to model your database on the real world, and in the real world peoples' names aren't unique.

Now, maybe 20th century US film actors have unique names. But that is an *accident*, not reality.

In the world of library science, a list of such things as actors' names is called a "controlled vocabulary." That's worth looking up if you want to learn about the ways of doing this kind of thing that have been worked out with centuries of experience.

To implement a controlled vocabulary in a DBMS, you would use a table with an (autoincrementing) id number. You'd put the person's name in a second column, the date of birth in another column, etc.  If the person has aliases (for example, "Prince", "The Artist Formerly Known As Prince," and "TAFKAP") you might include an aliases table in your vocabulary. This would contain pairs of id numbers.

(Notice that not even US Social Security Numbers are unique. The Social Security Administration once made the mistake of publishing a picture of a social security card; a lot of people use the number shown on that card.)

Don't worry about performance. The total number of movie actors, counting extras, doubles, and stunt artists, is well within the capabilities of a small DBMS system even with an ID number appended.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have two questions:

**1. Would it make sense to use actors full names as a primary key?**

This isn't impossible - but as noted by other commenters it is not advisable.  One reason being that actors may change their name (see also this [list of actors who have changed their name](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls003280390/)).

Also, more than one actor could feasibly have the same name, so full name is not a good candidate for a primary key.

You would be better off using a guaranteed unique field such as a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) or an [auto-increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html) field to identify your actors.

**2. What if performance is not an issue?**

I don't think this is really a performance issue, so much as a logical data modelling issue.  You could have an efficient primary key which is a string (such as a name) but in this case this would not be an appropriate field to use.